# construct DN with groovy

Tags: groovy, dn

I need to replace below code value with location value .

```
string str = "OU=Contractors,OU=Users,OU=Code,OU=Sites,DC=xyz,DC=com" ; 
DN = str.replaceAll( "Code" , LOCATION ) ;
```

I am getting incorrect signature of the method as string definition consist "=" and "," symbols . any help ?

Thanks.

Comment: a string can contain = and , .. That is _not_ the problem.  Please edit your question with exact error. I have given a speculative answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need go setting up the wrong string then use replace to make it right.

Just use templating to create the correct string. Ie:

```
String DN = "OU=Contractors,OU=Users,OU=$LOCATION,OU=Sites,DC=xyz,DC=com"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string str = "OU=Contractors,OU=Users,OU=Code,OU=Sites,DC=xyz,DC=com" ;
```

Looks wrong.  "string" is not a class. It must be `String` or `def`. Like below

```
 String str = "OU=Contractors,OU=Users,OU=Code,OU=Sites,DC=xyz,DC=com" ;
```

or

```
 def str = "OU=Contractors,OU=Users,OU=Code,OU=Sites,DC=xyz,DC=com" ;
```